# How to insert the missing months from an array in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-controller

I have here a query that I have returns `status` for each `months` when I try to use `dd($attr['month'])` this will return an array of this but as what I've checked it seems that it has some missing `months`.

```
private function getSummaryData($seller)
{
    $query = json_decode(json_encode(DB::select(DB::raw("select user_id, 
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%b %Y') ym,
    sum(IF(status='pending', 1, 0)) status_pending,
    sum(IF(status='success', 1, 0)) status_success
    FROM `case_summaries`
    WHERE user_id= " . $user->user->user_id . "
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%b %Y')
    ORDER BY created_at asc "))), true);

    $attr = [];
    $attr['month'] = [];
    $attr['pending'] = [];
    $attr['success'] = [];

    foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
        array_push($attr['month'], $value['ym']);
        array_push($attr['pending'], $value['status_pending']);
        array_push($attr['success'], $value['status_success']);
    }

    dd($attr['month']);

    return $attr;
}
```

**Result of Array for $attr['month']**

```
^ array:24 [
  0 => "Feb 2018"
  1 => "Mar 2018"
  2 => "Apr 2018"
  3 => "May 2018"
  4 => "Jun 2018"
  5 => "Jul 2018"
  6 => "Aug 2018"
  7 => "Sep 2018"
  8 => "Oct 2018"
  9 => "Nov 2018"
  10 => "Dec 2018"
  11 => "Jan 2019"
  12 => "Feb 2019"
  13 => "Mar 2019"
  14 => "Apr 2019"
  15 => "May 2019"
  16 => "Jul 2019"
  17 => "Aug 2019"
  18 => "Sep 2019"
  19 => "Oct 2019"
  20 => "Nov 2019"
  21 => "Dec 2019"
  22 => "Jan 2020"
  23 => "Mar 2020"
]
```

As you can see here that it has a missing month which is `Jun 2019`. How I can I add the missing months of the `query`?

I have this function here that getting all months between 2 dates

```
public function getMonthListFromDate(Carbon $date)
{
    $start    = new DateTime(); // Today date
    $end      = new DateTime($date->toDateTimeString()); // Create a datetime object from your Carbon object
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month'); // 1 month interval
    $period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end); // Get a set of date beetween the 2 period
    $months = array();
    foreach ($period as $dt) {
        $months[] = $dt->format("F Y");
    }
    return $months;
}
```

I'm having trouble here on how to implement this using `foreach` loop in my function `getSummaryData()` and then checks `if($attr['month'] == getMonthListFromDate())`. How can I add those missing months when passing them to my `query`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if your query data is not as required then you can generate complete array as per your requirements like

> ```
> $months = [
>     'Feb 2018',
>     'Mar 2020',
> ];
> $start_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($months[0]);
> $end_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($months[array_key_last($months)]);
>
> $months_diff = $start_date->diffInMonths($end_date);
>
>
> if (count($months) != $months_diff) {
>     $months = [$months[0]];
>     $add_month = $start_date->addMonth();
>     while ($add_month->lessThan($end_date)) {
>         $months[] = $add_month->format('M Y');
>         $add_month->addMonth();
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: The `$months` has to be dynamic @Zohaib because my query also gets the `months` and `years` in my database.

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano yeah what ever your query returns you can check if the count is equal to months difference than great, otherwise make your own array from start month to end month

Comment: so I need to refactor my function `getMonthListFromDate()` to your answer?